# Ruby on Rails - how to seed from a file "the right way"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an XML file containing data and I can easily parse it to insert the data into my rails database. The only problem is - in which directory should the file go into ("public" seems wrong, since the initial data in the database should not be public), and how do I refer to that file in the seeds.rb file (i.e. what prefix will guarantee that that file will be found).

This is a somewhat silly question but I haven't touched rails for a time now and they keep changing the directory structure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd simply put the file in a folder like `/db/data_source` because `seeds.rb` lives in `/db` so it keeps overall logic.

You can reference any file using:

```
"#{Rails.root}/path/to/file"
```